# The number of faces of a pointed convex polyhedral cone

Tags: convex-analysis, discrete-geometry, convex-cone

Let C be an n-dimensional pointed convex polyhedral cone with a uniqe frame {a1.a2.......,ar}, where  ais are  extrem half-lines.
Is there a formula for the number of r-faces in C?

Let me state the problem more concretely.
Consider the case n=3, where the frame of a 3-dimensional pointed convex polyhedral cone C is denoted by $\left( {{a}_{1}} \right),\cdots \left( {{a}_{r}} \right)\ \left( r\ge n \right)$.，where (a) means a halfline spaned by a. It can be seen from the figure that $\left( {{a}_{i}}\ {{a}_{i+1}} \right),1\le i\le r,$ is 2-dimensional faces of C, if necessary, by renumbering, where i+1=1 if i=r.
The number of n-1=2 dimensional faces is r. The number of n-2=1 dimensional faces is also r, since they lie on the common relative boundary of two adjacent 2 dimensional faces. The origin 0 is the only one n-3=0-dimensional face.
The n=3 case can be seen from the figure and proved, but is there a formula for finding the number of faces in each dimension for n > 3?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.